# An error occurs in the open part of the c code used by Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I am calling the function from C code.

```
FILE *temp;
char command[] = "dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency SurfaceView";
strcat(command,"" );
temp = popen(command, "r");
```

I call this once a second. But in about five minutes the process will be over. I checked the log and found that there was a problem in the open. But we don't know what caused it.

Comment: Do you ever close it?

Comment: What is `strcat` supposed to do? You can't add anything to that string. You should check the return value of `popen`.

Comment: I want to check the value of popen, but I cannot check the value because the process has ended. Do you happen to know how to view the error log?

Comment: Are you closing it every time before calling it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the cause. It was because I didn't "pclose" after doing "popen" elsewhere. I like to say, "Too many open files"